# Turn off Arduino Ethernet shield

Tags: arduino

To conserve battery life I would like to turn off the Arduino Ethernet shield (or put it in a low power state if this is possible). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You need to link data sheets for exact equipment you are using. How else is anyone going to give you a real answer?

Comment: edwbaker - it works:) I know it is an old post, but maybe someone has the same problem...
On the Arduino UNO board You actually have 2 pins connecting reset lines with Ethernet shield - one pin next to 3,3v, and one on the ICSP - pin 5. You probably bended / disconnected only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, the shield does not appear to support a native method.

However, a quick hack that only requires a single jumper wire and no significant tools, can add this feature.

The quickest and simplest way would be jump the Shields Reset to an available IO pin along with bending the Shields Reset Pin, as not to make contact with the Arduino's shield connector. This separates the shields reset from the Arduino's, allowing you to drive it directly.

This is similar to the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=behMgV3tUr4) that changes the IRQ pin, but same concept.

Note the W5100 is 3V and its reset is not directly tied to the Arduino, but rather to a Voltage Monitor along with a button that is wired-or'ed into the Arduino's Reset. It would be best to not to drive this pin as OUTPUT HIGH and LOW, but rather as INPUT for ON (the pull up will make it High for you) and OUTPUT LOW for Reset. This avoids a conflict of the Arduino being HIGH and the Button being low, which may burn out the Arduino's IO.

Comment: I tried that and it just stayed on permanently. I have discovered that by grounding the reset the wifi chip is turned off - is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: Basically. If you jump the reset pin to a spare Digital pin, and you then assert that pin as OUTPUT LOW (as stated above) it will be the same as simply shorting the reset to ground.

Comment: That doesn't work. Maybe the shield is drawing too high a current to sink via the digital pin?